# Getting the variance of each column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to calculate the variance of features saved in a Train and Test file a followed :

```
col1  Feature0  Feature1     Feature2   Feature3  Feature4  Feature5  Feature6  Feature7     Feature8     Feature9
col2     26658     40253.5  3.22115e+09  0.0277727   5.95939    266.56   734.248   307.364   0.000566779  0.000520574
col3     2658   4053.5     3.25e+09  0.0277   5.95939    266.56   734.248   307.364  0.000566779  0.000520574 
....
```

for that I've wrote the following :

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pandas as pd
#from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import preprocessing
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Reading csv file
training_file = 'Training.csv'
testing_file  = 'Test.csv'
Training_Frame = pd.read_csv(training_file)
Testing_Frame  = pd.read_csv(testing_file)
Training_Frame.shape
# Now we have the feature values saved we start
# with the standardisation of the those values
stdsc = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
np_scaled_train = stdsc.fit_transform(Training_Frame.iloc[:,:-2])

sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.2 * (1 - .2)))
sel.fit_transform(np_scaled_train)
pd_scaled_train = pd.DataFrame(data=np_scaled_train)
pd_scaled_train.to_csv('variance_result.csv',header=False, index=False)
```

This obviously doesn't work. the result  in `variance_result.csv` is just the train matrix normalized. 
So my question how can I get the index of the columns(features)  that have a variance bellow 20%.
thanks in advance !

**Update**

I've solved the variance issue this way  :

```
    import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pandas as pd
#from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import preprocessing
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold

# Reading csv file
training_file = 'Training.csv'
testing_file  = 'Test.csv'
Training_Frame = pd.read_csv(training_file)
Testing_Frame  = pd.read_csv(testing_file)

Training_Frame.shape
# Now we have the feature values saved we start
# with the standardisation of the those values
stdsc = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
np_scaled_train = stdsc.fit_transform(Training_Frame.iloc[:,:-2])
pd_scaled_train = pd.DataFrame(data=np_scaled_train)
variance =pd_scaled_train.apply(np.var,axis=0) 
pd_scaled_train.to_csv('variance_result.csv',header=False, index=False)
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(variance.values,Training_Frame.columns.values[:-2])
temp_df.T.to_csv('Training_features_variance.csv',index=False)
```

No I still don't know how to get indeces of features with a variance say bigger than `0.2` from `variance` other thanks running a loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the threshold to 0.0 and then use the `variances_` attribute of the VarianceThreshold object to get the variances of all your features, then you can identify which of them have lower variance.

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
X = [[0, 2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 4, 3], [0, 1, 1, 3]]
selector = VarianceThreshold()
selector.fit_transform(X)

selector.variances_
#Output: array([ 0.        ,  0.22222222,  2.88888889,  0.        ])
```